# Android text alignment changes when copying text

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the text that I have generated using my app:

[image]

But when I copy the text and post it as a YouTube comment, the alignment changes:

[image]

You can clearly see the difference here. Why does the alignment change and how do I rectify this error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code for copying the text:

```
copyBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val clipboardManager = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
            val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", finalString) // finalString is the string that is displayed on the screen
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Here is the xml code of the `TextView`:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayedText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="512dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: One mistake I see, ```android:layout_width="fill_parent"```, it should be "match_parent"

Comment: Yes. But that does not solve my problem :(

Comment: Also you should avoid margins of these values ```android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="512dp"```. These value are just too much.. You can use **chains**, **guidelines** and contraint one view to another, when using **ConstraintLayout**.

Comment: But my view is located properly on the screen only if I use these values. BTW, how is this connected to my problem?

Comment: @Sushil Can you give us the raw string(s) that your app should produce? Can you try pasting into another app such as Google Keep? Your problem might be using alignment rather than **leading spaces**

Comment: @xjcl Yes. You are right. When I removed `android:gravity="center"`, then this is how the text looked like: https://imgur.com/ry1gk6n Now how do I make sure that I copy the text with the alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy "alignment" -- text in a YouTube comment will always be left-aligned. Your only strategy here is to do left-aligned text in your app as well and then add spaces to the left of it. So maybe for line 3 around 0 spaces, for line 4 around 4 spaces, for line 5 around 8 spaces.

```
      * -- line 1 --
     * -- line 2 --
° -- line 3 --
    ' -- line 4 --
        ° -- line 5 --
```

As for the first line, YouTube comments automatically remove leading whitespace on the first line. You can't really do anything about that other than starting your star pattern on the first character of the first line, or adding a line of text above the star pattern.